# How to print or store html select tag with selected attribute based on values in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to print the following code with Laravel/PHP as html code. but it always print `value="cancelled">Cancelled` ! How I print or store the following html code in php/laravel?

```
    $row = Order::first();
    $csrf_token = csrf_token();
    echo '
    <form action="'.$row->update_url.'" method="post" class="form-inline">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.$csrf_token.'">
        <select name="status" id="status" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control">
            <option '.$row->status == "pending" ? "selected" : " ".' value="pending">Pending</option>
            <option '.$row->status == "confirmed" ? "selected" : " ".' value="confirmed">Confirmed</option>
            <option '.$row->status == "shipped" ? "selected" : " ".' value="shipped">Shipped</option>
            <option '.$row->status == "delivered" ? "selected" : " ".' value="delivered">Delivered</option>
            <option '.$row->status == "returned" ? "selected" : " ".' value="returned">Returned</option>
            <option '.$row->status == "cancelled" ? "selected" : " ".' value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        </select>
    </form>';
    die();
```

my main target is adding one column in datatables using yajrabox.

```
                    <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control"        >
                        <option value="pending" {{$order->status == 'pending' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Pending</option>
                        <option value="confirmed" {{$order->status == 'confirmed' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Confirmed</option>
                        <option value="shipped" {{$order->status == 'shipped' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Shipped</option>
                        <option value="delivered" {{$order->status == 'delivered' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Delivered</option>
                        <option value="returned" {{$order->status == 'returned' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Returned</option>
                        <option value="cancelled" {{$order->status == 'cancelled' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Cancelled</option>
                    </select>
```

where my yajra code look like this

```
            return \DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('invoiceno', function($row){
                        return $field=  <<<EOT
                        <a href="$row->full_url" class="badge badge-danger">$row->invoice_no</a>
EOT;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('orderStatus',function($row){
                        $csrf_token = csrf_token();
                        return $field = '
                        <form action="'.$row->update_url.'" method="post" class="form-inline">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.$csrf_token.'">
                            <select name="status" id="status" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control">
                                <option '.$row->status == "pending" ? "selected" : "".' value="pending">Pending</option>
                                <option '.$row->status == "confirmed" ? "selected" : "".' value="confirmed">Confirmed</option>
                                <option '.$row->status == "shipped" ? "selected" : "".' value="shipped">Shipped</option>
                                <option '.$row->status == "delivered" ? "selected" : "".' value="delivered">Delivered</option>
                                <option '.$row->status == "returned" ? "selected" : "".' value="returned">Returned</option>
                                <option '.$row->status == "cancelled" ? "selected" : "".' value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>';
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['invoiceno', 'orderStatus'])                    })
                    ->make(true);
```

Comment: I'm confused though. Right now, every option is being printed regardless, only the selected attribute is changing. Did you inspect the actual HTML that's being output to make sure the correct one is being marked as "selected"?

Comment: I want actually add a column using yajrabox in datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` concatenation operator is of higher precedence than the ternary operator, so your code is not doing what you think it is. Replace lines like this:

```
<option '.$row->status == "pending" ? "selected" : " ".' value="pending">Pending</option>
```

with lines like this:

```
<option ' . ($row->status == "pending" ? "selected" : " ") . ' value="pending">Pending</option>
```

Specifically, note the parentheses around `($row->status == "pending" ? "selected" : " ")`